# Light-cone coordinates and orthogonality

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I have a very basic question about light-cone coordinates. Any four-vector in space time can be rewritten from the usual way (one time, three-spatial) to light-cone coordinates
$$
(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3) \to (x^+, x^-, x^1, x^2) 
$$
where $x^{\pm} = (x^0 \pm x^3) / \sqrt{2}$. The metric under this "transformation" becomes
$$
\eta^{\text{usual coord.}}_{\mu,\nu} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\eta^{\text{light-cone coord.}}_{\mu,\nu}
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
x\cdot x = -(x_0)^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 \to -2x^+x^- + x_1^2 + x_2^2
$$.

Now, in the usual coordinates, I can have unit vectors pointing along the $x,y,z,\text{ and } t$ coordinates looking something like
$$
n_0 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},
n_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},
n_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},
n_3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that $n_i \cdot n_j = \eta_{ij}$ where $\eta_{ij}$ is the matrix element of the metric in the usual coordinates.
I am not sure how to do this under light-cone coordinates
$$
n_+ ?= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1/\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix},
n_{-} ?= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1/\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix},
n_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},
n_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here $n_i \cdot n_i = 1$ for $i \in \{1, 2\}$. However, when I expect $n^{\pm} \cdot n^{\pm} = 0$, when I work out the calculation explicitly using the light-cone metric I get
$\pm 1$. Likewise, when I expect $n^{\pm} \cdot n^{\mp} = \pm 1$, I instead get $0$.

So how do I go about defining unit vectors in light-cone coordinates? Is my definition of the light-cone metric wrong? And are the $+$ and $-$ coordinates orthogonal to each other or "parallel"?

Comment: To your first question, you are right. I'll make a modification, one of the four vectors "should" have a negative norm. By "unit vectors" I mean vectors that span space-time in light-cone coordinates. In that sense, I want these unit vectors to be orthogonal to one another, normalized, and span the entire vector space (any linear combination of them should give you any coordinate in space-time). Therefore there should be a unit vector in the $(+)$ direction and another in the $(-)$ direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want vectors pointing in the $+,-,1,2$ directions in light-cone coordinates then you actually just want $${n_+}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},{n_-}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},{n_1}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},{n_2}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$

(Note that the superscript $\mu$ denotes contravariant components.) A list of coordinates with a one in the $\nu$-th coordinate and zeroes elsewhere by definition denotes the vector pointing in the $\nu$-th direction. If you change the coordinate axes without changing the vector coordinates then those coordinates generally denote a different vector. Hence just declaring that you are using light-cone coordinates and not Cartesian ones is all you need to do to "find" the vectors pointing along the light-cone coordinate axes.

The things that you found are vectors pointing along the Cartesian axes, as expressed in light-cone coordinates. That's how you found them, isn't it? You took the coordinates of the Cartesian basis and put them through the change of coordinates formula. The whole purpose of the formula is to stop the physical vectors from changing by finding their new coordinates. So relabel the objects you've found as so

$${n_0}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}\\0\\0\\1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix},{n_1}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},{n_2}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},{n_3}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}\\0\\0\\-1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$

because physically they are still the Cartesian basis vectors.

P.S. Do note that $n_+,n_-$ are not unit vectors in the sense of having spacetime interval $\pm1$.

Comment: Thank you, this actually clears up a lot. Just one more question if you don't mind. Does this mean that $n_+^{\mu}$ is orthogonal to itself since $n_+ \cdot n_+ = 0$?

Comment: @user3166083 Yes, $n_+$ is orthogonal to itself.